# Find the next number in this sequence

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

Find the next number in the sequence :

> 1; 5; 33; 25; 2; 16; 14; 12; 11; ?

What is the next number and why ?

Comment: Is the answer a function? i dont like sequences where a number represents the length of a word or something similar

Comment: @Bedi, Hi, sorry for this late answer. No, there's no letter or words behind it, it's purely mathematics (i'll add this tag by the way).

Comment: @RémiHenry are you sure is it purely mathematics? Any clues?

Comment: Hmm... the 8th difference is -1016. Not really getting anywhere xD

Comment: is this sequence infinitely long?

Comment: I wasn't able to answer you yesterday, but yes, it's purely mathematical, and infinitely long.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The next number is

> **1**

The numbers come from this [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A033420) or this [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A118013), but any trailing zeros are removed.

In particular, this is the sequence without zeros removed:

> 100, 50, 33, 25, 20, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10

Comment: I hope thats not the answer, since i tried to figure that one out for a long period of time. But if i couldnt figure it out just because i didnt knew the OEIS sequence ist depressing

Comment: I mean, even w/o the OEIS sequence, the sequence itself is not too complicated once you figure out the trick. Look at [100/n].

Comment: Rot13(V gubhtug nobhg gur vairefr shapgvba, naq gnxvat gur svefg 2 ahzoref, rkpyhqvat 0.) But your solution works as well, congratulations ;)

Comment: Yes indeed. The trick was the the Zeros where removed. I may have found the [100/n] afterwards.